# Azure Virtual Machine setup Static IP

Tags: azure, static, ip, virtual

mydomain.com points to Azure VM.
What IP addresses must be static, so mydomain.com always work (after VM reboot)?

1. VIP and DIP
2. just VIP

> VIP – virtual IP address (public IP address associated with a VM)
>   DIP – dynamic IP address (local IP address associated with a VM)

Comment: This should be asked on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. That said: external dns knows nothing about internal Azure IP addresses.

Comment: You need to utilise a Reserved IP Address to set a fixed public IP. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690120.aspx

Comment: thanks, I have Reserved IP Address